# Does it make sense that Knuckle has a mascot as an emitter?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Knuckle Bine is listed as being a natural emitter but I am having difficultly reconciling that with his main power. As an emitter, the most difficult class for him to master is the conjuration and then (ignoring specialisation) transmutation.

His ability is to donate (sure you could call it emit) his Nen into another fighter. That Nen will gain interest until it reaches a point where it can force the other fighter into zetsu for 30 days.  The difficult thing to reconcil is that this Nen takes the shape of an indestructable mascot and has very unusual properties following very exact rules.

The creation of a physical manifestation is conjuration.  This creature appears to be made of Nen which means it wouldn't actually be a physical object (transmutation). These kinds of contracts/rule-following abilities seem to be tied to conjuration as well.  I could even buy that he is using manipulation to control the other person's Nen to force Zetsu.

Why is he labelled as an emitter?  Is his main ability emission or is he using a different type than his natural?  Do other emitters have such unusual Nen properties? (maybe the other ones I'm familiar with are just odd?)

Comment: It does make sense. Naturally, Nen user can use all of its categories but there is a special field in which he/she can fully master. For instance, Netero is an enhancer but he was able to create a Buddah(which is probably conjured) as a representation of his power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emitters can create beings made out of *nen*; it has been shown with Emitters in the dodgeball game. Razor creates his 14 devils and Goreinu creates his gorillas. These creatures are not conjured but are simply physically shaped *nen* made to do a task. The *nen* beasts are invisible to people without *nen* training and are controlled with manipulation which is similar to emission for this purpose.

The creatures can also have abilities giving to them, like Razor's devils being able to merge with each other and Goreinu's gorillas being able to teleport. This is how Knuckle creates the APR with the powers. It's mainly emission with a small bit of manipulation to give the APR its orders when it's created. These abilities look like conjuration but are actually complicated emission techniques.

Answer (score 0):

i saw a comment that says that an emitters "conjured beasts" or in knuckle's case apr are actually nen emissions that are pre-programmed to act a certain way and i think that is a cool explanation, i came here to offer a counter explanation that by setting rules and conditions knuckle could probably overcome his learning curve in conjuration while still being an emitter, just like how kurapika made his chains so strong by tailoring them to the troupe
and it could be viewed that the enforced zetsu isnt knuckle's ability directly but irs's ability which again could be gained and manifested as a result of his conditions being met i.e accuring a certain amount of interest.